# Android - Clicking on a WebView makes AppBar disappear.

Tags: android, webview, appbar

I am trying to allow WebView call in my application.  In this call they should be able to browse to another page.  I am also trying to keep a consistent AppBar for the application.

I have the .xml defined as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.realpayment.app.activities.CalledAction"
android:background="@color/c_black">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/JupiterTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"/>
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/calledAction"
    android:background="@color/c_black"
    android:layout_margin="15px"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:textColor="@color/c_white"
    />
```

In my code I am calling (I am playing with the options and found these in another SO post) but I starting with just the first and last line and see the same issue (I know in that case you can't click, but I accidentally had a redirect in my link):

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.calledAction);
    browser.setFocusable(true);
    browser.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    browser.loadUrl(sCallToActionLink);
```

This loads the link perfectly and my action bar is displayed.  The up button takes me to the parent activity and the back button takes me to the last activity called.  My problem is that if I click a link, it opens up a new screen with its own AppBar which does not have an up button.  This appears to be a completely different view.  The back button still works, but my plan is to provide an up button so that the user can navigate through the couple of screens she would like and then can hit the up button to go back to a reasonable place in my app.  In this case, the only recourse seems to be repeatedly hitting the back button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want the link to be opened within your own `WebView`?

Comment: Yes I do.  Is there a reason not to?  I just figured out that the WebView is firing off a browser intent and is no longer in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the link within your `WebView` if you set a `WebViewClient`

For API 24+ Override this method.

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you're supporting API < 24 then use the old method

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!  However, that call is deprecated.  I should be able to make use of 
    shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
though.  It seems to have some trickiness, but it should work.

Comment: @DanielleCox, actually it depends on what API you're targetting. I'll add in both methods.